# How to put std::dec/hex/oct into a look-up array

Tags: c++, arrays, lookup, std

I have this generic string to number conversion :

```
    enum STRING_BASE : signed int {
        BINARY  = -1,
        OCTAL   = 0,
        DECIMAL = 1,
        HEX     = 2,
    };
    template <class Class>
    static bool fromString(Class& t, const std::string& str, STRING_BASE base = DECIMAL) {
        if (base == BINARY) {
            t = (std::bitset<(sizeof(unsigned long)*8)>(str)).to_ulong();
            return true;
        }
        std::istringstream iss(str);
        std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&); /// have no idea how to turn this into a look-up array
        switch (base) {
            case OCTAL:     f = std::oct; break;
            case DECIMAL:   f = std::dec; break;
            case HEX:       f = std::hex; break;
        }
        return !(iss >> f >> t).fail();
    };
```

I would like to turn the *switch* case into a fine look-up array, something along these lines:

```
    std::ios_base arr[2] = {std::oct, std::dec, std::hex};
    return !(iss >> arr[(int)base] >> t).fail();
```

This produces : *error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &)' to 'std::ios_base'*

This won't work either :

```
std::ios_base& arr[2] = {std::oct, std::dec, std::hex};
```

I get : *error C2234: 'arr' : arrays of references are illegal*

So, is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
std::ios_base& (*arr[])( std::ios_base& ) = { std::oct, std::dec, std::hex };
```

Or with typedef for the function pointer:

```
typedef std::ios_base& (*ios_base_setter)( std::ios_base& );

ios_base_setter arr[] = { std::oct, std::dec, std::hex };
```

You can omit the array size, it will be deteremined from the number of initializers. I noticed this because you specified an array of size 2, but provided 3 initializers.